# Design Pattern - Single Object can only exist in single Event

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm looking for a suitable design pattern for this small game.

- a Player can only exist in single event
- but Player can be added(exist) in new Event as long as the old event terminated == true

What design pattern that will suit my scenario? Does my current setup make sense?

```
public class Player 
{
    public int id;  
    public Player(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

 public class Event 
 {
    public List<Player> allPlayer = new ArrayList<Player>();    
    public boolean terminated = false;
    public Event(){}        
    public void addPlayer(Player player){
        allPlayer.add(player);
    }       
}

public class Battle extends Event
{
    public Battle(){}   
}

public class Training extends Event
{    
    public Training(){}
}
```

Comment: Singleton pattern for Player class and Observer between Event (Subject) and Player (Observer). When Event finish, its players are notificated and they asign a variable "existsInAnyEvent" to false, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delegate the `Event` to the `Player` and when the event *terminates*, you can use the `terminated` flag to determine if you are able to associate the player with another event.

```
public class Player {
    private Event event;

    private int id;

    ...

    public void setEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
        if (!this.event.terminated) {
            throw new Exception("Player has an event to be associated with");
        } else {
            this.event = event;
        } 
    }
}
```

Note that there are also other ways to *notify* the `Player` that the `Event` has been terminated.

Comment: thanks sir, in setEvent method i need to do another check 
if(this.event.terminated == true)this.event = event;

Comment: Yes, I modified my answer accordingly :)

Comment: Beware the NullPointerException when `Player.event` is null. With the above code, you would not be able to call `setEvent` without causing an NPE.

Comment: thanks sir but i also need to check if(this.event != null) similiar before u edit it.. thanks

Comment: Another approach is to use a Schedule class that maintains the relationship of both Player and Event. In future, if a Player can be in multiple events or other such use case emerges you can do the change in Schedule class without Changing Player and Event.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a boolean parameter for Player : participating, which indicate whether an player is joining in one event.

```
public class Player {

public int id; 
public boolean participating;

public Player(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
//Get and Set method here...
}
```

In each event, just check for this attribute

```
public class Event {

public List<Player> allPlayer = new ArrayList<Player>();

public boolean terminated = false;

public Event(){}

public void addPlayer(Player player){
    if(player.getParticipating())//If the player is participating in other event, or already participating in this event, return
       return;
    allPlayer.add(player);
    player.setParticipating(true);
}

public void terminate(){
   for(Player p : allPlayer){
       p.setParticipating(false);
   }
   terminated = true;
}

}
```